# crm 2015 online prevent the possibility of adding new record from lookup

Tags: crm

Someone know any way to prevent the possibility of adding new record from lookup field?
I want that the users be able to choose only created records. but they couldn't create new from the lookUp.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a security role for your users defining the permissions you want them to have. You will need to have CREATE permission turned off on the lookup entity you don't want them to create.

One source with further information about Security Roles is here:
http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/business-administration/security-roles/